# Firebase Query PHP

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so I am in a kinda weird situation and have no idea how to do this:

I am using this awesome repo [kreait/firebase-php](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) to do all CRUD operations in my current application.

I used this code below to get the result I needed

```php
<?php
$data_page = $database->getReference('app/main_menu')->orderByChild('link')->equalTo($link)->getSnapshot()->getValue();
echo json_encode($data_page);
?>
```

I don't need the json anyway, but for better understanding of this question, I converted the array result into json format.

And from the code above, I manage to generate the result like this

```
{
  "-LhyRXILm9ALIfffuRaK": {
    "file_name": "personnel.php",
    "id": "-LhyRXILm9ALIfffuRaK",
    "link": "personnel",
    "parent": "master_human_rd",
    "status": "last_child",
    "title": "Personnel"
  }
}
```

The question is, how do I get the **file_name** from this result so I can include the matches file name and display the content?

Comment: `echo $data_page["-LhyRXILm9ALIfffuRaK"]['file_name'];`?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found the solution. I try to use `foreach` and it works, the code I am using to get the file name is below

```php
<?php
$data_page = $database->getReference('app/main_menu')->orderByChild('link')->equalTo($link)->getSnapshot()->getValue();
foreach ($data_page as $key => $value) {
  $file_name = $value['file_name'];
}
echo $file_name;
/*echo json_encode($data_page);*/
?>
```

Comment: Good to hear that you found the solution yourself, and thanks for sharing it. This looks like the correct way to get the value of a property from the results indeed. The only thing to keep in mind is that technically a query can have multiple matching nodes (which is why you need the `foreach` loop), and if that happens the above code will only show the file name of the last node in the results. It sounds like there will be at most one mathcing node in your current use-case, but it's something to keep in mind going forward.

Comment: What @FrankvanPuffelen said, and good to hear that you found the solution! If you want to be sure to get only one result in the query result, you could add `->limitToFirst(1)` to your query - this wouldn't prevent you from looping over the result, but at least you would loop just once.