# accessing nodes that are inside autogenerated keys in firebase

Tags: laravel, firebase-realtime-database

Good day.

I am working on a laravel app using firebase.
However, I am new to firebase and I am struggling with how to access the nodes inside the "Deliverers" node.
I can access the keys and everything in the "Deliverers" node. But I don't know how to access the nested nodes (Eg. Location, Profile, Each child in location or profile).
Any help at all will be greatly appreciated

I have created the service to connect to firebase this way:

```
namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Kreait\Firebase;
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
// The controller for this is called the TestController
class FirebaseService
{
    public static function connect()
    {
        $firebase = (new Factory)
            ->withServiceAccount(base_path(env('FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS')))
            ->withDatabaseUri(env("FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL"));
//I stored the credentials in my .env file.
        return $firebase->createDatabase();
    }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    private $database;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->database = \App\Services\FirebaseService::connect();
    }

    public function index() 
    {
        return response()->json($this->database->getReference('/Deliverers')->getValue());//this gives me everything in the Deliverers' node.
        return response()->json($this->database->getReference('/Deliverers')->getKey()->getChild("Profile")->getValue());//this is where I am struggling with
        
    }

}
```

This is what the JSON looks like

```
 "Deliverers" : {
    "1UWuDwL2WvWndqgUBweoUjeEEZk1" : {
      "Bank details" : {
        "accountName" : "Samuel Ken",
        "accountNumber" : "2344555",
        "bank" : "ZB"
      },
      "Location" : {
        "latitude" : "9.0691414",
        "longitude" : "7.4875424",
        "state" : "Abuja"
      },
      "Profile" : {
        "AccountStatus" : "Verified",
        "Address" : "hbuja",
        "BirthYear" : "1984",
        "DeliveryOn" : false,
        "Email" : "f@mail.com",
        "From" : "Federal Capital Territory",
      }
    },
     "1UWuDwL2WvWndqgUBweoxxedr" : {
      "Bank details" : {
        "accountName" : "Mitch Ken",
        "accountNumber" : "2344555",
        "bank" : "ZB"
      },
      "Location" : {
        "latitude" : "9.0691414",
        "longitude" : "7.4875424",
        "state" : "Abuja"
      },
      "Profile" : {
        "AccountStatus" : "Verified",
        "Address" : "hbuja",
        "BirthYear" : "1984",
        "DeliveryOn" : false,
        "Email" : "f@mail.com",
        "From" : "Federal Capital Territory",
      }
    },
}
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question (there's a link right under it) to include the [minimum, complete/standalone code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thanks! I have added the code in my Controller.

Comment: I'm not sure what `FirebaseService` is in your code, but does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56723463/209103

Comment: Thanks a lot @FrankvanPuffelen for being patient with me. I have edited my question again. I am grateful for the link, but it did not help me much as I could not really understand the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately that makes it hard to help. Did you try to `foreach` over the value as shown there? What happened when you did that? Was there an error message? Did you log any values?